Simulation Nodes Motion Blur
Can someone explain to me why the motion blur behaves so strangely when using simulation nodes?
Even if I give the individual points their own ID, a motion blur is strangely rendered, but at the same time the instance is overlaid without a motion blur. What is this? Only blurred lines should be visible, not sharp cubes.
Does anyone understand this?
My Node Setup:

The Result:

Thanks for help!

For every frame you add new cubes to the simulation zone, via the Join Geometry node. These new cubes has no movement until the next frame.

You're right, but that doesn't matter because the cubes are added at the bottom. All the cubes shown in the picture are part of the simulation node loop and were not just added.
